Norix, Bavarian son of Hercules?
William Smith's Dictionary of Greek and Roman Geography states:

The name Noricum, is traced by some to Norix, a son of Hercules, but
was in all probability derived from Noreia, the capital of the
country.

No source is cited for this Norix. I have seen some cite the Annolied, which I actually did find an English translation of, but at least the translation I read made no reference to Norix or Hercules.
German wikipedia cites the Vita Altmanni, which I have been unable to find a translation or original language version of. German wikipedia also raises the question whether Norix is meant to be a son of Greco-Roman Hercules or Alemanus Hercules, a different legendary figure of Germany said to be compared to Hercules for his greatness.
Websites that mention Norix also seem to contradict each other as to whether he was meant to have been born in Bavaria or have been one of the Armenians who conquered Bavaria in legend.
So my questions are: Can someone cite me the source for the Norix legend? Was Norix meant to be the son of Hercules from Greco-Roman mythology or Alemanus Hercules of German mythology? Was Norix said to be Bavarian or one of the invading Armenians, or born after the legendary Armenian invasion?

This is the relevant passage from the Vita Altmanni, which I found via the Deutsche Digitale Bibliothek.

Hic mons in Norico Ripensi situs, primatum tenet inter montes circumjacentes, amœnitate, jocunditate, fertilitate, salubritate. Et quia Noricum nominavimus, ethimologiam ejus si placet, exprimamus. Bawarii traduntur ab Armenia oriundi, qui cum magna multitudine de finibus suis egressi, hanc terram sunt ingreffi: & expulsis Aboriginibus, pro eis habitaverunt, & terram de nomine Ducis sui Bawaro, Bawariam nominaverunt. Hanc post multos dies Norix filius Herculis expugnans, Noricum ex suo nomine vocavit: in qua & civitatem Tyburtinam, qua nunc Ratispona dicitur, ædificavit. Ripensis autem, que nunc Orientalis dicitur, ideo vocatur, quia subductis montibus, ripa Danubii undique vineis & arvis fæcundatur. Sed qualiter hic mons ad tantam profecerit gloriam, paucis expediam.
Anonymo Coenobita Gottwiciensi (c. 1140). Vita Beati Altmanni Episcopi Pataviensis §28. In Hieronymus Pez, editor (1721). Scriptorum Rerum Austriacarum, tome 1, columnae 128. Lipsiae: Joh. Frid. Gleditschii.


This mountain,† situated in Riverine Noricum, holds primacy among the surrounding mountains for delight, charm, fertility, and health. And since we named Noricum, we will discuss its etymology, if it please. The Bavarians, who are said to come from Armenia, came forth from their borders in a great multitude, invaded this land, and expelled the inhabitants, in order to settle there, and they named the land Bavaria after their leader Bavarus. Subduing them after many days, Norix, the son of Hercules, called it Noricum after his name, in which he also built the city of Tyburtina, which is now called Ratisbon. However, in the so-called Riverine Noricum, which is now known as Eastern Noricum, the bank of the Danube, which rises from the mountains, is everywhere fruitful with vineyards and farms. But how this mountain rose to such prominence, I will briefly expound.
Anonymous monk of Göttweig Abbey (c. 1140). Life of the Blessed Altmann, Bishop of Passau §28. In Hieronymus Pez, editor (1721). Austrian Writings, volume 1, column 128. Leipzig: Johann Friedrich Gleditsch.
† The writer seems to be using “mons” (mountain) in the sense of an elevated site for an abbey or monastery. I think the “mons” under discussion is Göttweig Abbey, which overlooks the Danube as described.

Later sources seem to derive from the Vita Altmanni without adding any information. Here, for example, is a passing mention of Norix, son of Hercules, in a 15th-century manuscript.

Si quando uero pro communi utilitate prouidendum erat, communis etiam contributio pro aedificiis fiebant, miroque modo aggrestis populus fortalitium totum lateribus instaurabat, in suamque uoluntatem quam plurimos nobiles, qui in montibus, ubi Norix filius Herculis a qua Norica dicta, moram fecerat, habitabant, circumquaque attraxit.
Sigismundo Meisterlein (1480). Exaratio Rerum Gestarum Inclutae Civitatis Newronbergensium, cap. 2. In Ioannes Petri de Ludewig (1727). Reliquiae Manuscriptorum Omnis Aevi Diplomatum ac Monumentorum, tomo IIX. Francoforti et Lipsiae.


If it was truly necessary at some time to provide for the common benefit, a common contribution was also made for buildings, and in a marvelous manner the people of the district rebuilt the whole fortress in brick, and at their will attracted as many nobles as possible from all around, who were living in the mountains, where Norix, the son of Hercules, after whom Noricum is called, had lingered.
Sigmund Meisterlein (1480). Account of the Proceedings of the State of Nuremberg, chapter 2, pages 11–12. In Johann Peter von Ludewig (1727). Remains of Manuscripts, Letters, and Monuments of All Eras, book 12. Frankfurt and Leipzig.

And here’s a later text which closely follows the Vita Altmanni but introduces errors that likely originated in the difficulty the scribe had in reading an exemplar in a Gothic script employing minims. Thus the original “Bawarii” (Bavarians) has been miscopied as “Boiarii” (Boyars) and “Bawaro” (the name of their leader) as “Banaro”. We can tell that this must have been a mistake as “Bavaria” can’t have been named after “Banarus”.

Et quia Noricum nominauimus, etymologiam eius si placet exprimamus. Boiarii traduntur ab Armenia oriundi, qui cum magna multitudine de finibus suis egressi, hanc terram sunt ingressi, expulsisque Aboriginibus, pro eis habitauere, & terram de nomine ducis Banaro Bauariam nominauerunt. Hanc post multos dies, Norix filius Heraculis expugnans, Noricum de suo nomine vocauit.
Wolfgango Lazio (1600). De Gentium Aliquot Migrationibus, liber 2, pagina 28. Francofurti: Andreæ Wecheli.


And since we named Noricum, we will discuss its etymology, if it please. The Boyars, who are said to come from Armenia, came forth from their borders in a great multitude, invaded this land, and expelled the inhabitants, in order to settle there, and they named the land Bavaria after their leader Banarus. Subduing them after many days, Norix, the son of Hercules, called it Noricum after his name.
Wolfgang Laz (1600). On Some Migrations of Peoples, book 2, page 28. Frankfurt: Andrea Wechel.


I did my best with the Latin, but I'm not sure I managed to construe it all, so please make corrections. Meisterlein has the most abominable style, piling up clauses by centre embedding so that we are left at the end with a heap of verbs.

Thank you so much for finding and even translating the passage of Vita Altmanni and others!
It also seems all the oldest sources favored Greco-Roman Hercules before Annius of Viterbo invented Hercules Alemannus.
All my questions I found unanswerable have been answered by you!
